# Visual C# Express 2010 IDE crashes when loading a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

This problem started after the last failed run on my project. The IDE crashed and now when I reopen the C# project the error appears. Opening other projects is fine.

Comment: Open a second copy of VS and attach its debugger to the first copy to see what the exception is.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the .suo file for your project. I have had it get corrupted before and cause Visual Studio to crash while opening the project. The file will be recreated when you load your project.